# Import code from file using awk in bash

Tags: bash, awk

We'd like to import code between two strings and put them in an variable.

**We have:**

```
job=1

listen="$(awk -v a="BEGIN-$job" -v e="END-$job" '/BEGIN {print a}/{p=1;next} /BEGIN {print e}/{p=0;exit} p' whatsthat.file)"
```

**whatsthat.file (edited):**

```
BEGIN-1

echo "some code"

END-1

BEGIN-2

echo "next job"

END-2
```

**Final result for variable `$listen` should be:**

```
echo "some code"
```

But the command above leaves `$listen` *empty*.

Comment: Of course it does not work -- it's a no-sense. What is `/BEGIN {print a}/` for? Do you know what `/···/` means?

Comment: E.g. if you have `awk /BEGIN/{p=1;next} /END/{p=0;exit} p' whatsthat.file` and only BEGIN and END in whatsthat.file it works. So the // are for checking the code between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `awk` command has several problems, what you're looking for is this:

```
job=1

listen="$(
awk -v a="BEGIN-$job" -v e="END-$job" '$0==a {p=1;next} $0==e {exit} p && NF' whatsthat.file
)"
```

- *Patterns* `$0==a` and `$0==e` check the input line at hand (`$0`) against the variables `a` and `b` for equality. If so, the associated *action* (`{...}`) is executed.
- `{p=1;next}`, which is executed for the start of the range of interest, sets (conceptually) Boolean flag `p` and moves to the next input line; its purpose is to indicate that subsequent lines - due to being inside the range of interest - should (potentially) be printed.
- `{exit}`, which is executed for the end of the range, unconditionally ends processing (the range-ending line, just like the range-starting one, shouldn't be printed).
- `p && NF` is a pattern that tests flag `p` and whether the input line is nonempty (`NF` contains the number of whitespace-separated fields on the line, and that number is `0` for empty or blank lines); if both conditions are met, the input line at hand is implicitly printed (which is Awk's default action in the absence of an action associated with a pattern).